# How do I create a polygon with an ArcGIS 10.1 python addin

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, arcmap, python-addin

I'm looking for some code samples, or help with code to get me started.   I've built a python addin menu which I would like to use to create polygon features in a specific layer in my edit session.  [image]

So for example I would click 30x60 and a 30m x 60m rectangular polygon would be placed where I click.
I can't seem to find much on creating geometry within a python addin.
Thanks in advance for any comments or suggestions.
Frank

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that currently, as far as I can tell, there is no way to get the current editable layer(s). See: [How to get the editor's current layer in ArcPy?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/77881/753)

So as an alternative you could have the user select a layer from the TOC and use the `GetSelectedTOCLayerOrDataFrame` method in the [`pythonaddins`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/The_pythonaddins_module/014p00000021000000/) module to retrieve it.

If you can get over that, here is how you could implement the rest in a Python add-in:

1. Implement a function that takes an x and y map coordinate, width and height dimensions for a rectangle, and a layer/feature class. The function then opens an [`InsertCursor`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w0000000t000000) on the layer, creates a new [`Polygon`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018z00000061000000) from the input coordinates and width and height, and inserts it using the cursor's `insertRow` method. Test this method outside of the add-in framework until you are sure it works as you expect.

   Below is a function I came up with that seems to work (it considers the x and y arguments to be the lower-left corner of the rectangle):

   ```
   def createRectangleAtPoint(x, y, width, height, layer):
       desc = arcpy.Describe(layer)
       bottom_left = (x, y)
       top_left = (x, y + height)
       top_right = (x + width, y + height)
       bottom_right = (x + width, y)
       array = arcpy.Array([arcpy.Point(*coords) for coords in [bottom_left, top_left, top_right, bottom_right, bottom_left]])
       rect = arcpy.Polygon(array, desc.spatialReference)
       with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(layer, "SHAPE@") as cursor:
          cursor.insertRow((rect,))
   ```
2. In the implementation for your [`Tool`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//014p00000027000000) class, listen for `onMouseUpMap`, retrieve the `x` and `y` coordinate arguments, and pass these in, along with the desired dimensions and layer, into the function above.
3. Implement an [`Extension`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Application_Extension/014p00000019000000/) class that listens for `onStartEditing`, `onStopEditing`. Enable and disable your tool object when the edit session starts and stops.

   **Note:** Consider this step optional since this doesn't really prevent the user from running the code on a non-editable layer or one outside of the current edit session though, so there isn't that much point right now.

Comment: Oh wow, thanks Blah!   I can't wait to give this a try.

Comment: To get the x,y coordinate of my starting location I'm guessing I need to use the onMouseDownMap function.  However when I run the tool the mouse seems to lose snapping functionality which I need.   Is there a tool property for snapping?

Comment: I don't think so, but you might want to clarify your requirements in your question.